# Matplotlib: Setting margin on distribution and analyzing the margin shift as the parameters change

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have kind of hit a dead-end with this so I thought of asking the most helpful community on here for some suggestion/help. Here it is...

I am writing a python script that plots distributions. I have set margins on the PDF and the CDF subplots using a mouse click event such that when I click on the PDF or CDF plot it registers the x-value and creates a vertical grey area (using `axvspan`) from the point of click through till the end of the x-axes. See pic below

[image]

Question:

The issue I am facing here is that the grey area created (x-value registered) upon click, disappears when the slider values are changed. I would ideally like python to freeze the x-value upon click and show the shift of grey area as the slider value changes. How can I achieve this?

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm, uniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons, CheckButtons

#####Generating random data#####

ix = 0
mu_a1 = 1
sigma_a1 =  0.14
mu_b1 = 10
sigma_b1 =  1.16
mu_c1 = -13
sigma_c1 =  2.87
mu_x01 = -11
sigma_x01 =  1.9

a1 = 0.75*mu_a1 + (1.25 - 0.75)*sigma_a1*np.random.sample(size=10000)
b1 = 8*mu_b1 + (12 - 8)*sigma_b1*np.random.sample(size=10000)
c1 = -12*mu_c1 + 2*sigma_c1*np.random.sample(size=10000)
x01 = (-b1 - np.sqrt(b1**2 - (4*a1*c1)))/(2*a1)

#####_____#####

#####Creating subplots & plotting distributions#####

fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.13,right=0.99,bottom=0.05)

def draw_ax1():
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(331)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.set_xlabel('a' , fontsize = 14)
    return ax1

def plot_ax1():
    ax1 = draw_ax1()
    [n1,bins1,patches] = ax1.hist(a1, bins=50, color = 'red',alpha = 0.5, normed = True)
    return ax1

def draw_ax2():
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(334)
    ax2.clear()
    ax2.set_xlabel('b' , fontsize = 14)
    ax2.grid(True)
    return ax2

def plot_ax2():
    ax2 = draw_ax2()
    [n2,bins2,patches] = ax2.hist(b1, bins=50, color = 'red',alpha = 0.5, normed = True)
    return ax2

def draw_ax3():
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(337)
    ax3.clear()
    ax3.set_xlabel('c' , fontsize = 14)
    ax3.grid(True)
    return ax3

def plot_ax3():
    ax3 = draw_ax3()
    [n3,bins3,patches] = ax3.hist(c1, bins=50, color = 'red',alpha = 0.5, normed = True)
    return ax3

def draw_ax45():
    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(132)
    ax4.clear()
    ax4.set_xlabel('x0' , fontsize = 14)
    ax4.grid(True)
    ax5 = fig.add_subplot(133)
    ax5.clear()
    ax5.set_xlabel('x0' , fontsize = 14)
    ax5.set_ylabel('CDF', fontsize = 14)
    ax5.grid(True)
    return ax4, ax5

def plot_ax45():
    ax4, ax5 = draw_ax45()
    [n4,bins4,patches] = ax4.hist(x01, bins=50, color = 'red',alpha = 0.5, normed = True)
    ax4.axvline(np.mean(x01), color = 'black', linestyle = 'dashed', lw = 2)    
    dx = bins4[1] - bins4[0]
    CDF = np.cumsum(n4)*dx
    ax5.plot(bins4[1:], CDF, color = 'red')
    return ax4,ax5

ax1 = plot_ax1()
ax2 = plot_ax2()
ax3 = plot_ax3()
ax4, ax5 = plot_ax45()

#####Event handler for button_press_event#####

def onclick_update(a):
    xmin = a
    xmax = ax4.get_xlim()[1]
    ax4.axvspan(xmin, xmax, facecolor='0.9', alpha=0.5)
    ax5.axvspan(xmin, xmax, facecolor='0.9', alpha=0.5)
    return a

def onclick(event):
    '''
    Event handler for button_press_event
    @param event MouseEvent
    '''
    global ix
    ix = event.xdata    
    for i, ax in enumerate([ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5]):
        if ax1 == event.inaxes:
            print "Click is in axes ax{}".format(i+1)
        if ax2 == event.inaxes:
            print "Click is in axes ax{}".format(i+2)
        if ax3 == event.inaxes:
            print "Click is in axes ax{}".format(i+3)
        if event.inaxes in [ax4, ax5]:
            if ix is not None:
                print 'x = %f' %(ix)
            plot_ax45()
            onclick_update(ix)
            plt.draw()
            return ix
        else:
            return

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

#####_____#####


#####Creating Sliders#####

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axmu_slider1 = plt.axes([0.015, 0.67, 0.07, 0.015], axisbg=axcolor)
axsigma_slider1 = plt.axes([0.015, 0.65, 0.07, 0.015], axisbg=axcolor)
mu_slider1 = Slider(axmu_slider1, 'M', -13.0 , 10.0, valinit = 1.0)
sigma_slider1 = Slider(axsigma_slider1, 'SD', -3.0 , 3.0, valinit =1.0)

axmu_slider2 = plt.axes([0.015, 0.37, 0.07, 0.015], axisbg=axcolor)
axsigma_slider2 = plt.axes([0.015, 0.35, 0.07, 0.015], axisbg=axcolor)
mu_slider2 = Slider(axmu_slider2, 'M', -13.0 , 10.0, valinit = 1.0)
sigma_slider2 = Slider(axsigma_slider2, 'SD', -3.0 , 3.0, valinit =1.0)

axmu_slider3 = plt.axes([0.015, 0.07, 0.07, 0.015], axisbg=axcolor)
axsigma_slider3 = plt.axes([0.015, 0.05, 0.07, 0.015], axisbg=axcolor)
mu_slider3 = Slider(axmu_slider3, 'M', -13.0 , 10.0, valinit = 1.0)
sigma_slider3 = Slider(axsigma_slider3, 'SD', -3.0 , 3.0, valinit =1.0)

#####_____#####

#####Updating Sliders#####

def updateval_slider1(mu,sigma):
    global a1
    a1 = 0.75*mu + (1.25 - 0.75)*sigma*np.random.sample(10000)
    global x01
    x01 = (-b1 - np.sqrt(b1**2 - (4*a1*c1)))/(2*a1)
    draw_ax1()
    draw_ax45()
    plot_ax1()
    plot_ax45()        
    return ax1, ax4, ax5

def update_slider1(val):
    global mu_a1
    mu_a1 = mu_slider1.val
    print mu_a1
    global sigma_a1
    sigma_a1 = sigma_slider1.val
    print sigma_a1
    updateval_slider1(mu_a1,sigma_a1)
    plt.draw()

mu_slider1.on_changed(update_slider1)
sigma_slider1.on_changed(update_slider1)

def updateval_slider2(mu,sigma):
    global b1
    b1 = 8*mu + (12 - 8)*sigma*np.random.sample(10000)
    global x01
    x01 = (-b1 - np.sqrt(b1**2 - (4*a1*c1)))/(2*a1)
    draw_ax2()
    draw_ax45()
    plot_ax2()
    plot_ax45()        
    return ax2, ax4, ax5

def update_slider2(val):
    mu_b1 = mu_slider2.val
    print mu_b1
    sigma_b1 = sigma_slider2.val
    print sigma_b1
    updateval_slider2(mu_b1,sigma_b1)
    plt.draw()

mu_slider2.on_changed(update_slider2)
sigma_slider2.on_changed(update_slider2)

def updateval_slider3(mu,sigma):
    global c1
    c1 = -12*mu + 2*sigma*np.random.sample(10000)
    c1 = c1[~np.isnan(c1)]
    global x01
    x01 = (-b1 - np.sqrt(b1**2 - (4*a1*c1)))/(2*a1)
    draw_ax3()
    draw_ax45()
    plot_ax3()
    plot_ax45()            
    return ax3, ax4, ax5

def update_slider3(val):
    mu_c1 = mu_slider3.val
    print mu_c1
    sigma_c1 = sigma_slider3.val
    print sigma_c1
    updateval_slider3(mu_c1,sigma_c1)
    plt.draw()

mu_slider3.on_changed(update_slider3)
sigma_slider3.on_changed(update_slider3)

#####_____#####

plt.show()
```

An example code would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: @Ophir Carmi - I would appreciate if you may have any suggestions or perhaps a way to achieve this :-).